# Can't get onMouseEnter to change state in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a className to a div using react components. This is what I have. I'm fairly new to react, btw.

```
class PrimaryNavigation extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      condition: false
    };
  }

  onMouseEnterHandler() {
    this.setState({
      condition: !this.state.condition
    });
  }

  clickHandlerFor(component) {
    return (e) => {
      if (typeof this.props.onClick !== 'function') {
        return;
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      var componentData = this.componentDataFor(component);
      this.props.onClick(e, componentData);
    };
  }

  componentDataFor(component) {
    ...
  }

  render(): ReactElement {
    ...
    return (
      <div className='PrimaryNavigation'>
        <nav className='PrimaryNavigation-Links'>
          <ul>
            ...
            <li className="dropdown" onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnterHandler}>
              <Link to='/account' className='PrimaryNavigation-link dropbtn'>
                <span className='PrimaryNavigation-label'><FormattedMessage id='navigation.my_account' /></span>
              </Link>
              <div id="myDropdown" className={this.state.condition ? "dropdown-content show" : "dropdown-content" }>
                <div className="dropdown-box">
                ...
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For the div that has the ternary condition in it, if I keep it as `this.state.condition` then the className of `"dropdown-content"` shows up. When I change it to `!this.state.condition` then the classname of `"dropdown-content show"` shows up. meaning the issue I'm having is changing the state. in my `onMouseEnterHandler()` function I have changed condition to being true. Still nothing.

What can I do? Also, if i've phrased my question incorrectly, any edit suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: If you put a console.log in the `onMouseEnterHandler` does it ever log that it is being triggered?

Comment: Is `onMouseEnterHandler` bound to the correct context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the `onMouseEnterHandler()` method to the component instance in your constructor, otherwise the `this` context won't be the component and `setState()` will be undefined.  See updated code:

```
class PrimaryNavigation extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      condition: false
    };

    this.onMouseEnterHandler = this.onMouseEnterHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onMouseEnterHandler() {
    this.setState({
      condition: !this.state.condition
    });
  }

  clickHandlerFor(component) {
    return (e) => {
      if (typeof this.props.onClick !== 'function') {
        return;
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      var componentData = this.componentDataFor(component);
      this.props.onClick(e, componentData);
    };
  }

  componentDataFor(component) {
    ...
  }

  render(): ReactElement {
    ...
    return (
      <div className='PrimaryNavigation'>
        <nav className='PrimaryNavigation-Links'>
          <ul>
            ...
            <li className="dropdown" onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnterHandler}>
              <Link to='/account' className='PrimaryNavigation-link dropbtn'>
                <span className='PrimaryNavigation-label'><FormattedMessage id='navigation.my_account' /></span>
              </Link>
              <div id="myDropdown" className={this.state.condition ? "dropdown-content show" : "dropdown-content" }>
                <div className="dropdown-box">
                ...
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See relevant React documentation here: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding

Comment: Daniel, thank you! I'll look into the documents and check out binding.

Comment: It's worth noting that this applies to any method you want to call as an event callback (click, mouse enter, window resize, key press, et al). You should [almost] _always_ bind these callbacks to their instance. Often times you will see developers use an array of function names which should be bound during construction... something like this: `['handleClick', 'someOtherFunction'].forEach(fn => this[fn] = this[fn].bind(this));`

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for the note. I'll pay attention to when I want to call a method as an event callback.